# Backbone js view for entire html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, backbone.js

I want to make a view for html document inside an iframe. For something like:

```
<div id="some">
    <iframe id="other" />
</div>
```

I want to dynamically load an html document received from server into this iframe. The problem is, that I want to use Backbone View for that document. If I do something like this:

```
var projectView = Backbone.View.extend(
{
    tagName: 'html',


    initialize: function()
    {
        this.model.bind('sync', this.render, this);
    },


    render: function()
    {
        this.$el.html(this.model.get('content')); // content is from model, and it     
        //receives the html document from server
        return this;
    }
});
```

Then, when I do:

```
var iframe = $('#other')[0].contentWindow.document;
iframeDocument.open();
iframeDocument.write(projectView.render().el);
iframeDocument.close();
```

It does not work. I tryed a lot of different combinations but no success. If I use document.write() with static html it works fine but how to do with backbone view and dynamic content?

Comment: What is the value of `projectView.render().el` just before `write` gets called?

Comment: Well, it's a JavaScript Object: [object HTMLIFrameElement]. If I put the content in a div, it is completely normal html document. Doesn't work for iframe though. In the browser console it seems to be html document.

Answer (score 4):

The "el" property is a reference to an HTML object. You're passing it into a document.write() call when that function is actually expecting an HTML string. Which is why static HTML works for you.

So you'd probably want to do something like this:

```
iframeDocument.open();
iframeDocument.write(projectView.render().el.innerHTML);
iframeDocument.close();
```

Comment: Sorry, actually it does not work. I still can't get the html from el.

Answer (score 3):

I think your approach is unnecessarily complex and using backbone isn't buying you anything useful. Why don't you just set the `iframe`s `src` attribute with the model's `content` URL and be done with it?

```
render: function()
{
    this.$el.attr('src', this.model.url()); //Or whatever you need to get the right URL
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Well... I'm trying to use this approach because the content for the iframe is in a database. The entire html doc is in a DB. After I fetch the content I will dynamically change it and after that I want to persist it again.

Comment: You might be right, this might not be the best approach. I'm still trying to figure out if I should filter the document(removing some tags) and embed it in a div, or to load it entirely in an iframe.

The src approach won't work for me, after all, I will change the content of the document dynamically.

Comment: Yes, but why don't you just do that within the iframe document itself? That will avoid annoying cross-origin restrictions as well.

Comment: Do you mean that the framed document changes itself? Hmmm... that's an idea. On the other hand, changes have to be applied when events on base document are triggered. Anyway, I'll think about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use an iframe.

You can just replace the iframe with a div and it will render every time your sync event is triggered.

You can also use `on` instead of `bind` for the event.

```
var projectView = Backbone.View.extend(
{
    tagName: 'div',


    initialize: function()
    {
        this.model.on('sync', this.render, this);
    },


    render: function()
    {
        this.$el.html(this.model.get('content')); // content is from model, and it     
        //receives the html document from server
        return this;
    }
});
```

and then just put the view into a container

```
$('#some').html(projectView.el);
```

you may have to remove some unnecessary content(ie. `<head>` tags) from the model whenever it syncs

Comment: I'll try your suggestion but I'm still not convinced that div approach is clean enough. I might be wrong but have to try by myself.